# Can $x^x$ be a natural number for non-integer $x$?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

Does some real non-integral $x$ exist such that $x^x$ equals a natural number?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Try $x = 2.3161454958785612301325503$. With greater precision than I can give here, you can get $x^x$ very close to exactly $7.0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function $x^x$ is continuous, and becomes very large for large $x$. It follows by the Intermediate Value Theorem that **every** integer $n\ge 1$ is $x^x$ for some real $x$.

Comment: Thanks,  this is so obvious now.

Will x always be transcendental or could it be rational was probably what I was thinking?

Comment: @TomCV If $x>0$ and $x^x\in\mathbb N$, then $x$ is either rational or transcendental; that is, it cannot be an irrational algebraic number. See the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).

Comment: You are welcome. Your question, as mentioned by triple_sec, is settled by Gelfond-Schneider.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm still curious about whether such an $x$ can ever be a non-integer rational, or must it always be either whole or transcendental.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it should be impossible for non-integer rationals, but I may be missing an obvious case. @triple_sec

Comment: It cannot be a non-integer rational.

Comment: The real question is, when is $$e^{W(\ln{n})}$$ rational? With $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see it now. If $x$ were a non-integer rational and $x^x=k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, then $x=m/n$ for some positive coprime integers $m,n$ such that $n\neq1$. But then, $m^m=n^m\cdot k^n$, so $m$ and $n$ must have at least one common prime factor—a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, if $p/q$ we take the $q$-th power.